# What improvements does GCC's `__builtin_malloc()` provide over plain `malloc()`?

Tags: c, gcc

I have recently been made aware of GCC's built-in functions for some of the C library's memory management functions, specifically `__builtin_malloc()` and related built-ins (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).  Upon learning about `__builtin_malloc()`, I was wondering how it might work to provide performance improvements over the plain `malloc()` related library routines.

For example, if the function succeeds, it has to provide a block that can be freed by a call to plain `free()` since the pointer might be freed by a module that was compiled without `__builtin_malloc()` or `__builtin_free()` enabled (or am I wrong about this,and if `__builtin_malloc()` is used, the builtins must be globally used?).  Therefore the allocated object has to be something that can be managed with the data structures that plain `malloc()` and `free()` deal with.

I can't find any details of how `__builtin_malloc()` works or what it does exactly (I'm not a compiler dev, so spelunking through GCC source code isn't in my wheelhouse).  In some simple tests where I've tried calling `__builtin_malloc()` directly, it simply ends up being emitted in the object code as a call to plain `malloc()`.  However, there might be subtlety or platform detail that I'm not providing in these simple tests.

What kinds of performance improvements can `__builtin_malloc()` provide over a call to plain `malloc()`?  Does `__builtin_malloc()` have a dependency on the rather complex data structures that glibc's `malloc()` implementation use?  Or conversely, does glibc's `malloc()`/`free()` have some code to deal with blocks that might be allocated by `__builtin_malloc()`?

Basically, how does it work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe there is no special GCC-internal implementation of `__builtin_malloc()`. Rather, it exists as a builtin only so it can be optimized away under certain circumstances.

Take this example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *p = malloc(4);
    *p = 7;
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

If we disable builtins (with `-fno-builtins`) and look at the generated output:

```
$ gcc -fno-builtins -O1 -Wall -Wextra builtin_malloc.c && objdump -d -Mintel a.out

0000000000400580 <main>:
  400580:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  400584:   bf 04 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x4
  400589:   e8 f2 fe ff ff          call   400480 <malloc@plt>
  40058e:   c7 00 07 00 00 00       mov    DWORD PTR [rax],0x7
  400594:   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
  400597:   e8 b4 fe ff ff          call   400450 <free@plt>
  40059c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4005a1:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  4005a5:   c3                      ret
```

Calls to `malloc`/`free` are emitted, as expected.

However, by allowing `malloc` to be a builtin,

```
$ gcc -O1 -Wall -Wextra builtin_malloc.c && objdump -d -Mintel a.out

00000000004004f0 <main>:
  4004f0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4004f5:   c3                      ret
```

All of `main()` was optimized away!

Essentially, by allowing `malloc` to be a builtin, GCC is free to eliminate calls if its result is never used, because there are no additional side-effects.

---

It's the same mechanism that allows "wasteful" calls to `printf` to be changed to calls to `puts`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Builtins disabled:

```
$ gcc -fno-builtin -O1 -Wall builtin_printf.c && objdump -d -Mintel a.out

0000000000400530 <main>:
  400530:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  400534:   bf e0 05 40 00          mov    edi,0x4005e0
  400539:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  40053e:   e8 cd fe ff ff          call   400410 <printf@plt>
  400543:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  400548:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  40054c:   c3                      ret
```

Builtins enabled:

```
gcc -O1 -Wall builtin_printf.c && objdump -d -Mintel a.out

0000000000400530 <main>:
  400530:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  400534:   bf e0 05 40 00          mov    edi,0x4005e0
  400539:   e8 d2 fe ff ff          call   400410 <puts@plt>
  40053e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  400543:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  400547:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Interesting and useful explanation. So the essential feature of the built-in version is that it can guarantee a known behavior to the compiler, which allows it to be optimized away, and perhaps to receive other optimizations as well...

Comment: @DanLenski That's how I see it. After a number of experiments, the only thing I can get GCC to do "special" with `__builtin_malloc` is to optimize it away. I tried passing it `0`, but passing the result to another (external) function caused a call to `malloc` to be emitted.

Comment: The compiler probably knows that the result of __builtin_malloc doesn't alias with any other pointer. Say your function has int* p as a parameter and calls int* q = malloc (sizeof int); *q = 1; then the compiler knows that this assignment hasn't modified *p.

Comment: What you hint to in your answer, but what would be useful to state explicitly, is that a call to a declared function `malloc` is normally translated to a call to `__builtin_malloc`, and a call to `__builtin_malloc` is normally translated to a call to an external library function `malloc`. You describe the second part of that, but the first part is also relevant: it matters because it shows that there is almost never a need for the user to actually spell out `__builtin_malloc`: it works even if the user just uses plain old `malloc`.